# Opera Extension - Detecting a key pressed and then clicking and holding at mouse location for 1 second

Tags: opera, mouseclick-event

How would you detect if say the letter 'a' on the keyboard is pressed... and if it is, perform an action where you click and hold at the mouse location for 1 second? I'm completely new to Opera Extensions and I'm not even sure how to run the script in the Opera browser.

**EDIT:** Changed JavaScript to Opera Extension.

Comment: Are you saying you want to programatically fire a mouse down / mouse up event to the browser? I don't think that is possible in javascript. However, if you can figure out which object is under the mouse, you can send events directly to that object.

Comment: @aj_r Yes, that is what I'm saying. Are you sure you can't do it? I read that on Opera you can run your own JS across multiple sites.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your edit. If you are writing an Opera extension, I have no experience in that area. Ignore my previous comment.

Comment: I was able to use Sikuli to simulate the desired behavior using hotkeys and low-level mouse events.

Answer (score 0):

show keycode number

```
$(function () {
  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     $('body').text(e.keyCode);
  });
});
```

now

```
 $(function () {
  $(document).keyup(function (e) {
     if(e.keyCode==65){    //letter a
          //some code
     }
  });
});
```

Comment: This only answers half of the question.

Comment: @avril for the "//some code" part, how would I do a mouse click and hold for 1 second?

Comment: `setInterval(function () {alert("one second")}, 1000);` or `myVar=setTimeout("javascript function", milliseconds);`